# Show LWC for specific page in Experience Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-builder-page

Just like LWC can be configured to show only for a particular object, is there any config which can make LWC show only for certain pages of Experience builder?
Ex: in Commerce LWR site, there are many components which are available on certain pages not on all pages.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Targets defined in the configuration file control where these are exposed.

In the case of [Experience Cloud targets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder), we have the following to choose from:

- `lightningCommunity__Page` to create a drag-and-drop component that appears in the Components panel
- `lightningCommunity__Page_Layout` to create a page layout component for LWR sites that appears in the Content Layout window
- `lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout` to create a theme layout component for LWR sites that appears in Settings in the Theme area

Choosing the appropriate target will then restrict where that component is available.